# Problem with drawing ellipse with code.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to draw an ellipse. This is the code. 
The logic I am using is to start with "Bigger" radius, and then uniformly decreasing it to "Smaller" radius. 
But i am getting this output :

[image]

that does not look like ellipse.

```
var a:Number =0; 
var container_Mc:MovieClip ;

var w = 550/2 ;
var h = 400/2 ;

var k =0; 
for ( var i =0 ; i< 360; i++,k++ )
{

    if( i % 90 == 0 )
    {

        k=0
        swap(w,h) ;
          a = (w-h)/90 ;

    }
    var rad = getRadFromDeg(i);
    var hypo = (h) + a*k;;

    var xx =Math.cos( rad ) *  hypo

    rad = getRadFromDeg(i);
    var yy = Math.sin( rad) *  hypo


   drawPoint(xx,yy)

}
```

I also referred this question :
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/what-is-a-simple-algorithm-for-calculating-evenly-distributed-points-on-an-ellip

The answer, uses integration, which i am not able to understand. Can anyone please throw some light, on how should i distribute the radial distances, so that it looks like ellipse ?

Comment: mh the question should be emigrated to porgramming stack exchange

Comment: Why *should* thi slook like an ellipse at all? Why don't you simply plot `(w*Math.cos(rad),h*Math.sin(rad))`?

Comment: It's a question about mathematical concept. I added "code" just in case someone wanna look at the algorithm. I don't wanna get the code, i only wanna know, the right way to find it out.

Comment: @Hagen : (w*Math.cos(rad),h*Math.sin(rad)) is an equation of ellipse ?

Comment: Simplify your loop a little :

for ( var i =0 ; i< 360; i++)
   drawPoint(Math.cos(getRadFromDeg(i)) * w, Math.sin(getRadFromDeg(i)) * h)

Comment: @VishwasGagrani Yes, the usual parametric form. However, the points are not equidistributed wrt arc length. If $w\approx h$ this makes little difference. Why do you want equal distance in the first place? More specifically, how much tolerance would you accept? What about direct euclidean distance instead of arc length? Can you use more "advanced" plotting methods such as Bezier curves (which themselves can only approximate elliptic arcs, but quite well)?

Comment: Well, just wanted to understand, how ellipse is made. I thought, ellipse is just about equal division of arc from bigger to smaller radius. However, when i saw the output, it was wierd. So, was trying to figure out, how the points are distributed then. What rule ? 
Anyways, i will directly use the simple parametric form then, and see if it works! :)
Thanks.

Comment: As already stated, this doesn't work because that simply is not the formula for an ellipse. This page is a javascript implementation of an ellipse, with the gist of the code printed beneath it. http://fiddle.jshell.net/gLnJn/show/

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151936/finding-points-on-ellipse/153192#153192

Comment: The gamedev posts you linked to are about placing points at **equal arclengths** on an ellipse. That's even harder than placing them at equal angle increments, which is what you seem to be doing. The easiest approach is to just pick some suitable set of parametric equations, and then place points at **equal parameter values**. I gave the qual-angle solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want points at equal angle increments, then the equations you need are:

$$s  =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{  {b^2}\cos^2{\theta} + {a^2}\sin^2{\theta}  }}$$

$$x = sab \cos\theta$$

$$y = sab \sin\theta$$

In other words, you need to use $\text{hypo} = sab$. Here, $a$ and $b$ are the semi-axes of the ellipse, as usual.

These equations are derived from the polar equation of the standard ellipse, which is explained on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center). The polar equation (relative to the ellipse center) is:

$$r  =  \frac{ab}{\sqrt{  {b^2}\cos^2{\theta} + {a^2}\sin^2{\theta}  }}$$

But, there is no good reason to place points at equal angular increments, so you may as well use the nice simple equations that the other answers gave.

If you want fast code, either use the forward differencing trick I mentioned in my other answer, or use the equations:

$$  x = \frac{a(1-t^2)}{1+t^2} \quad ; \quad y = \frac{2bt}{1+t^2}$$

Comment: Why and where did S come from ? I mean, what rule has made you make the conclusion of using "s" in the algorithm.

Comment: The $s$ shows up if you take a line at angle $\theta$ and intersect it with the ellipse $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$. In other words, it's an essential part of the polar equation of an ellipse. And, if you want equal angle increments, you ought to be thinking in terms of polar equations.