# Length of chord on ellipse

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, conic-sections

Suppose I have an ellipse centered at the origin, preferably expressed in its matrix form, and I want to know the chord length of a segment that passes through the origin with the endpoints at the ellipse, of which I know the angle theta. How can I compute it? Thank you!

Comment: what is theta? Is it the parametric angle or the angle made by the x axis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the parametric equation of the ellipse to be $(a\cos\theta, b\sin\theta)$ where a is the semi-major axis and b is the semi-minor axis. Since an ellipse is a central curve, the origin bisects the chord and therefore the length of the chord is twice its distance from the origin, i.e., $$2\sqrt{(a\cos \theta)^{2}+(b\sin \theta)^{2}}$$

Comment: And what if the ellipse were tilted? I mean, a general ellipse/ellipsoid in matrix form?

Comment: @user116773, just add (deduct) the ellipse's inclination angle.

Answer (score 1):

If your chord makes an angle $\phi$ with the $x$-axis, then its length is
$$
\frac{2ab}{\sqrt{  {b^2}\cos^2{\phi} + {a^2}\sin^2{\phi}  }}
$$
See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326349/problem-with-drawing-ellipse-with-code/326429#326429) for a bit more detail.

The angle $\theta$ used in apurv's answer is *not* the angle between the chord and the $x$-axis. That's probably the reason for his question, where he asked you what you mean by "theta".

Answer (score -1):

The answer from Bubba assumes the chord passes through the center, so it's actually a diameter.  If you start with parametric equations [x,y]=R*[cos(phi),sin(phi)], substitute them into the equation for an ellipse, and solve for R, you get half of Bubba's answer.