# How to find points of Cassinian curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, computational-geometry

I would like to calculate and plot the points of a 2D Cassinian curve in a Cartesian plane.

The Cassinian curves are those curves for which the product of the distances of the points belonging to the curve from 2 other points, called foci, is constant:

$$r_1 = |p-a|$$
$$r_2 = |p-b|$$
$$r_1 r_2 = k$$

The curves are shown in the figure. The outer curves have a bigger value of k.

[image: Cassinian curves.]

My idea, given one curve hence one $k$ is to iterate using from $0$ to $2\pi$ and calculate at each step the x-value(s) and y-value(s) but I do not know which calculations I should perform (particularly when the result is 2 closed non-intersecting curves).

I could find something similar but for the ellipsis [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151936/finding-points-on-ellipse)

Comment: Can't you use the explicit equation in terms of coordinates $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @YuriyS ok for MathJax...P is the point of the curve, a, b are the foci (just like in an ellipse). Consequently r are the distances from the foci (again like an ellipse). I could not find anything in the links you posted: please note the picture was taken from there, this means I checked that site. If you see a solution in that page please make it explicit since I could not find it there.

Comment: Your system does not work. Each time I should solve a quadratic expression in x and another in y to get x and y. This is at least inefficient. I have to code this expression in some programming language. Consider a circle: instead of using the quadratic equation it is much easier to say x=Rcos(theta); y=Rsin(theta) letting theta varying from 0 to 2pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the center of the cassinian, $S$ and $T$ its foci, $P$ a point on the curve, and set:

$$a=OS=OT$$
$$r=OP$$
$$\theta=\angle SOP$$

From the cosine rule applied to triangle $SOP$ we get:
$$PS^2=a^2+r^2-2ar\cos\theta$$

and from the same rule applied to triangle $TOP$ we get $$PT^2=a^2+r^2+2ar\cos\theta$$

Multiplying together those two equalities, and remembering that $PS\cdot PT=k$, we obtain the equation:
$$
k^2=(a^2+r^2)^2-4a^2r^2\cos^2\theta,
$$
which can be solved for $r^2$ to yield
the polar equation of the curve:
$$
r^2=a^2\left(\cos2\theta\pm\sqrt{{k^2\over a^4}-\sin^2 2\theta}   \right).
$$

If $k/a^2\ge1$ then one value of $r^2$ is negative and must be discarded, so you get a single value of $r$ for each $\theta$.

If $k/a^2<1$ both values are positive but they exist only for $|\sin2\theta|\le k/a^2$: in this case you have two separate branches.

Once you have computed $r$ you can the find the coordinates of point $P$ as usual:
$$
x=r\cos\theta,\quad y=r\sin\theta.
$$

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I implemented it in python and it seems to work.
The strange thing is that the 2 branches are not the left closed circle-like curve and then the right one. On the contrary each branch seems to contain points of both the left and right closed curves.

Comment: Actually thinking about that it makes sense because one set is for |sin2θ|≤k/a^2 which will be like -some_const<theta<some_const and the other set for the other values